# Safe way of creating new QDialog object

Tags: c++, qt

I am writing a Qt application where I have `QListWidget` filled with `QListWidgetItems` and I want to create a new dialog on double click on `QListWidgetItem`. So I created a new dialog class as in [this](https://doc.qt.io/qtvstools/qtvstools-getting-started.html) qt tutorial. Now, I added `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)` slot where I should create an instance of dialog class. But I want my main app to still operate and continue and just have dialog window show some info. So I cant just create an instance of dialog class and show it with `exec()` function.

So what i came up with is to have `std::unique_ptr` on my dialog class as class member of my main class, and invoke dialog with `show()` method. Everytime `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)` is called I will create new instance of dialog class with `std::make_unique` which should destroy old dialog and create a new one.

Is this generally a safe approach ? Or is there other standard way of solving such situation ?

**EDIT**

Here is example how I was thinking it might look:

The main class:

```
class USB_Packet_Analyzer : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    USB_Packet_Analyzer(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);    
private:
    Ui::USB_Packet_AnalyzerClass ui;
    std::unique_ptr<DataViewer> dataViewer;
private slots:
    void on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item);
};


void USB_Packet_Analyzer::on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    dataViewer = std::make_unique<DataViewer>(item, this);
    dataViewer->show();
}
```

Dialog class :

```
class DataViewer : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    DataViewer(QListWidgetItem* item, QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~DataViewer();

private:
    Ui::DataViewer ui;
};
```

Comment: post the code, it looks like you need t define a class member dialog somewhere....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes what you are doing is fine. There are some minor issues you may want to address:

1. Closing the dialog does not free the memory. The memory will be consumed until the `unique_ptr` is destroyed.
2. The `unique_ptr` is not cleared when the dialog is closed. This may be fine now, but if you try to use that `unique_ptr` later it may be a problem.

These may not cause problems now, but they may in the future. This is why I could suggest the following edits:

```
void USB_Packet_Analyzer::on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked(QListWidgetItem* item)
{
    if (!dataViewer.isNull()) dataViewer->deleteLater();
    dataViewer = QPointer(new DataViewer(item, this));
    dataViewer ->setAttribute(Qt::WidgetAttribute::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    dataViewer->show();
}
```

`QPointer` allows you to easily detect if the widget has been deleted.

While technically your usage of `unique_ptr` is safe, it is dangerous to use `QObject` classes in smart pointers. `QObject` lifetimes are usually managed through parent-child relationships. Because the smart pointers don't know about this, it is VERY easy to get double frees when doing this. I would recommend you go with the `QPointer` version because of this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just have some follow up questions on what you've said. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that `DataViewer` class will live as long as I will point on it with `unique_ptr` so how can there be double freeing ? The `unique_ptr` will be reused on every `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked` call, which should stop pointing on the last dialog(I assume this is where dialog is destroyed and it's memory is freed) and create new dialog. Or is `DataViewer` dialog destroyed on closing the dialog using red cross even though `unique_ptr` is pointing on it ?

Comment: In the general case of storing a `QObject` class in a `unique_ptr`, the object can be deleted while still in the `unique_ptr`. Qt manages lifetimes with parent child relationships. When the Parent is destroyed, the children are also. Qt has no idea about your usage of smart pointers and so happily deletes it. Then, when you `unique_ptr` is destroyed, it is deleted again. By default, the dialog is not deleted when closed. That is why your code is technically safe. However, it is generally best to delete the dialog when closed to release the memory back to the system.

Comment: Hmm, if you are actually assigning a parent to your `DataViewer` object then your code is not safe and is at risk of double frees. I was assuming that you had not assigned a parent because it was its own window. If you give a dialog a parent then (besides the lifetime issues because of your use of `unique_ptr`) it will not show in the taskbar which is a bad user experience.

Comment: So what my options are : 1. using `unique_ptr` but creating `DataViewer` with nullptr as parent. Therefore when `USB_Packet_Analyzer` will be destroyed there will only be deleting by `unique_ptr` and not by Qt child relationship. 2. Using `QPointer` with `DataViewer` parent set to `USB_Packet_Analyzer` . Therefore when closing `DataViewer` dialog it will be destroyed because of `WA_DeleteOnClose` attribute. But what if `USB_Packet_Analyzer` will be closed while `DataViewer` is still open ? Will it be destroyed thanks to Qt child relationship because `DataViewer` is its child ?

Comment: Yes, if `USB_Packet_Analyzer ` is the parent of `DataViewer ` then it will be deleted when `USB_Packet_Analyzer ` is deleted. Note that (at least on Windows), giving the Dialog a parent prevents it from showing in the task bar as a separate Window. If you want to avoid that and still have `DataViewer` closed/deleted when `USB_Packet_Analyzer ` you can do this when creating the `DataViewer`: `connect(usbPA, &QObject::destroyed, *dataViewer, &QObject::deleteLater)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will use `QPointer` and create `DataViewer` with `nullptr` parent. I'm just having some issues with your `connect` method. I am calling it in `on_listWidget_itemDoubleClicked ` right after creating `DataViewer` like this : `connect(this, &QObject::destroyed, *dataViewer, &QObject::deleteLater);` but its giving me an "no instance of overloaded function "USB_Packet_Analyzer::connect" matches the argument list" error. Any ideas whats wrong ?

Comment: Hmm my mistake I think, the connect call needs `dataViewer.get()` instead of `*dataViewer`

Comment: I assume you mean `dataViewer.data()` since `QPointer` has no `get()` method. Anyways, thank you very much, you answer is very appreciated and helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you dont need a special custom made dialog  for just showing a couple lines of info
use instead the MessageBox...

```
 QMessageBox::information(this, "some title", "my text");
```

Comment: I would like to have a few `QTableViews` and `QTreeViews` in that dialog that will show custom data which will be provided by custom models, so it will be a little more complicated than just showing a couple lines of info.